# Why are there so many structs?

Tags: c, malloc

I'm a beginner and I don't understand why this bit of code doesn't crash. How can there be so many planes[i] when I allocate planes using malloc(1)?

```
int main()
{

    typedef struct Flight2{
        int altitude;
        int longitude;
        int latitude;

    }Flight;

    Flight *planes;
    planes = (Flight*)malloc(1);
    if (planes == NULL) {
     printf("Error in allocating the data array.\n");

    }
    printf("%d.\n",sizeof(Flight));
    planes[0].altitude = 1000;
    planes[100].altitude = 1200;
    printf("0: %d\n",planes[0].altitude);
    free((void*)planes);
    printf("100: %d",planes[100].altitude);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There can't. Accessing memory out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as does accessing memory you have free'd. And one of the things with *undefined behavior* is that it might *seem* to work sometimes, while other times it causes [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: I hope you realise that `malloc(1)` doesn't even allocate memory for *one* `Flight` struct. It allocates one byte.

Comment: So planes[100].altitude is a place in the memory that I can access even though it hasn't been specified what it means?

Comment: You can access any place in memory you please. Some will cause a segfault, some will work incorrectly, and some will only appear to work.

Comment: Ok, but why doesn't it complain about that it's undeclared, or is it declared?

Comment: Because you declared a pointer. But you failed to allocate enough memory. C has no checking of array access at runtime (although the compiler checks that an array is large enough if you initialise its elements).

Comment: In C, array bounds checking is the job of the programmer (that's you). You didn't do that job, and there was nothing else in place to do it for you.

Comment: Alright, then I'm happy.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have undefined behavior at the first place where you access the `planes` array. Anything could happen from that point on. However, here is an explanation of what *is actually* happening in your case. What I'm saying here should never be relied on, nevertheless it is instructive to understand what is happening behind the scenes.

Your structure has a size of 12 bytes (at least on my system). Thus, 100 `Flight` objects require 1200 bytes of memory. That is important because the system manages your process's memory in terms of memory pages, and a memory page has 4096 bytes on X86 hardware. So, what happens is this:

1. You request one byte from `malloc()`.
2. The `malloc()` implementation has no memory do dish out, yet, so it asks the system kernel for memory.
3. The system kernel hands the `malloc()` implementation at least one entire page.
4. The `malloc()` implementation writes some private data to the memory page to be able to return it to you in many small pieces.
5. The `malloc()` implementation returns a pointer within that page. This quite likely points to a higher address than where it has stored its own private data. But this depends on the `malloc()` implementation.
6. You write to memory at offsets 0 to 3 and 1188-1191 from this pointer.

   This does not fail because it is still within the memory page, so the hardware and the system kernel think this access is ok. It is (only) the definition of `malloc()` that is in conflict with what you are doing.
7. Since you have not clobbered any vital private data of your `malloc()` implementation, the `free()` call does not realize that something fishy has been going on, and you program terminates normally.

Note, that the apparent successful behavior of your program depends on the fact that there is only one allocation in it. If you insert a second `malloc()` call after the first one, you *might* get a crash because you *might* be overwriting data that's private to your `malloc()` implementation. This could cause `free()` to abort your program with an error message, lead to faulty behavior of other `malloc()` calls, crash your program in any way, or do anything else. If you insert the second `malloc()` call in front of the first one, you might cause the allocation to happen at the end of a memory page, which *might* give you a segfault. But nothing is for certain once you enter the land of undefined behavior.

Btw: If you run your program with `valgrind`, it will tell you exactly where you went wrong and how. It's really a great tool that you should familiarize yourself with.